# How to validate real, practical, commonly accepted email addresses (but including unicode)?

Tags: php, regex, email, unicode

How to validate real, practical, commonly accepted email addresses (but including unicode)?

The topic of validating email addresses has come up a lot on SO, and it often gets distracted by the fact email addresses are theoretically allowed to contain a lot of "special" characters. Some say many email validators are too strict, but the fact is if GMail, facebook, Yahoo etc. are very strict, that means 99.999% of emails out there will conform to those standards which are more strict than what the RFC will allow, so that's the REAL world.

I've done a survey (14-01-19) of free email services and here are some of the most common restrictions on email names:

GMail:        NOT allowed: ! " # $ % & ( ) * + , / : ; < = > ? @ [ \ ] ^ ` { | } ~

Yahoo.com:    Only letters, numbers, underscores(_), and ONE dot (.) are allowed:

Zoho.com:     Only letters, numbers, underscores(_), and dots (.) are allowed:

facebook.com: Only letters, numbers, underscores(_), dots (.), and hyphen (-) are allowed:

hushmail.com: Only letters, numbers, underscores(_), dots (.), and hyphen (-) are allowed:

AIM (AOL):    Characters NOT allowed:  @, !, * or $ (many others too, but not specified)

Hotmail/Outlook.com:  Letters, numbers, _-. OK; no accented or non-Latin alphabet

iCloud.com:   Typical Apple, you have to download a bunch of crap (67.5 MBytes) and let it 
                invade your system before you can even create an account. I didn't bother.

The bottom line is that the vast majority of email services only allow letters, numbers, underscores(_), dots (.), and hyphen (-).  Also, I know from reading about this on many sites that quite a few people use '+' in their email address.

So, I'd like a nice simple filter to screen out any emails that are invalid because of overall structure or because they use anything other than the simple characters used by the vast majority of people and/or accepted by most email services: A-Z a-z 0-9 _.+-

Unfortunately PHP's filter_var function with FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL/FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL allows these characters to get through:  !#$%&'*/=?^`{|}~@[]  and so I consider it virtually useless - especially since it allows the quote (') symbol.  Only the most geeky nerds will use any of those symbols in their email address and if they do, they'll be rejected by the vast majority of sites, so they must have a more normal backup email address anyway.

One complication: I live in Vietnam and must allow for the possibility of unicode characters in the addresses.  How can I do that?

Comment: Why would you do this? Why would you turn away some portion of potential customers, when doing the right thing is not only easy, it's *easier* than what you're proposing?

Comment: ... the right thing being, sending an E-Mail with a confirmation link. Problem solved. Bonus: you know the address actually belongs to the user

Comment: You /could/ if you really wanted to check to make sure there are no spaces and only one @ symbol, but that's about it.

Comment: @Pekka: Sometimes trying to send a bunch of invalid emails is a penalty by MX Server by putting your server in black list.

Comment: Every time this issue arises it goes off onto topics such as "why not allow every conceivable email?" or "do the email w/ confirmation link" - my question was so long winded to try to avoid these. If the person entering their email accidentally hit the ' key I'd like to catch that immediately since there's a 99.9999% chance that was a mistake. Also, I don't want the person to think all is well, finish registration, then not get a confirmation email because it was sent to a totally unlikely address instead of his real one. I'm willing to sacrifice a few macro-nerd customers for this.

Comment: Building some insanely complex rule (that is guaranteed to become outdated before long, what with new TLDs, new types of IDNs...)  to catch an extremely unlikely kind of typo, while letting through the vast majority of *real* typos which still look like a valid address, sounds like a super bad idea. And the number of people  using E-Mail outside Facebook, GMail and co. is guaranteed to be in the hundreds of millions, not just some obscure half percent of nerds.

Comment: # Active users: Facebook 1,310,000,000; Gmail: 425 million; hotmail: 325 million; Yahoo: 298 million;

Comment: # of people with these symbols !#$%&'*/=?^`{|}~[] in their email address: hard to say, but very few I think, and probably less than half percent!

Comment: A half percent of a billion is still five million. But either way, what sense does it make to exclude *any* group of customers for almost zero gain? As said, the vast majority of typos is going to be switched characters á la `johndoe@gmali.com` or `jhondoe@gmail.com` that are still technically valid.

Comment: Following the principle of multiple levels of security (ie. EVEN IF I USED PREPARED STATEMENTS), isn't it safer to weed out dangerous symbols such as single/double quotes,pipes,=,braces, etc. from email addresses before letting them into my system? If facebook and Google are willing to sacrifice "millions" of potential customers with these symbols in their email addresses (mostly hackers and geeks), shouldn't my little e-commerce app do the same? Anyone using those symbols MUST have cleaner email addresses to use any of the popular sites. I want them to use those addresses on my site too

Answer (score 4):

The only correct way to validate an E-Mail address is to send a an E-Mail with a confirmation link to it.

If you feel so inclined, check for a general `(string)@(string).(string)` pattern to catch user mistakes and obvious bogus entries like `lalalalala`.

The [`filter_var` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php) (that you already mention) does that.

Anything beyond that is a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways for an email to be invalid. And it's not just in using characters. Validating some formats of string doesn't fit in Regular Expression. For instance having double dots (`..`) in a email address is invalid, which you should put it out the reqex.

You can take a look at [Zend_Validate_EmailAddress](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.set.email_address). If you check the source code you will get the complexity of the problem.

```
// Split email address up and disallow '..'
if ((strpos($value, '..') !== false) or
    (!preg_match('/^(.+)@([^@]+)$/', $value, $matches))) {

    ...
}

$this->_localPart = $matches[1];
$this->_hostname  = $matches[2];

...

    $hostname = $this->_validateHostnamePart();
...
$local = $this->_validateLocalPart();
```

And in _validateLocalPart they do this:

```
// atext: ALPHA / DIGIT / and "!", "#", "$", "%", "&", "'", "*",
//        "+", "-", "/", "=", "?", "^", "_", "`", "{", "|", "}", "~"
$atext = 'a-zA-Z0-9\x21\x23\x24\x25\x26\x27\x2a\x2b\x2d\x2f\x3d\x3f\x5e\x5f\x60\x7b\x7c\x7d\x7e';
if (preg_match('/^[' . $atext . ']+(\x2e+[' . $atext . ']+)*$/', $this->_localPart)) {
    ...
}
```